# Block the application in Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

For my application I have implemented a system that detects if the current version is an old version that requires an update. By the way the detection work as intended.

My problem is how to block the application use when that happens. By now I'm launching an activity for inform the user and grant a link to the Market. My problem is that if the user press the back button returns to the last Activity and I dont know how to change the

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

For exit the application when the user press backs and don't go back to the other activities.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to close other activities/processes from your application?

Comment: Take a look Here,[how to close application when multiple activities are alive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421004/how-to-close-application-when-multiple-activities-are-alive).

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` on the other activities, but I'm not sure how you'd get a reference to them.

To my knowledge the Android system does not let the programmer end tasks (which contain multiple activities in their back stacks), which is what you're trying to do.

You could try using Fragments instead of Activities, which will let you communicate information and events between them.

Answer (score 0):

Before laucnhing the new activity, make sure to call finish() on main activity (outdated version of main app) to remove from back stack.