# Android "Back" button manipulate

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities A and B. Activity A calls Activity B, and when pressing "back", Activity A will return, where this is great. The problem is that when I go to B from A, and then i exit the app, when i return i will see Activity B, But this time, pressing "Back" will exit the app again. So my question is - How to overcome this problem so when i come back to the app to Activity B, pressing "Back" will return me to Activity A ?

Comment: just override back button behavior with the OnKeyDown event.

Comment: Could you tell android version?

Comment: Are you doing any back press manipulation already? The behavior you described does not sound normal.

Answer (score 7):

Override the back button, and then start you activity A from that. For example

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
       //start activity A here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

On the other hand, if your app is for newer devices only (API level 5 I think) you can do this instead

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //start activity here
        super.onBackPressed();   


    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this solution can make the Activity Manager wrong? So when pressing back button will go back to B from A? or overhead it?

Comment: @LiranRitkop Each activity can override the back button in a different way, so if you do this in activity B, but not in activity A then the default action of the back button will not change when the users presses it in activity A

Comment: Well, it almost worked. Now when pressing Back on A I get to B instead of exiting the app as default. So now i do finish() to the activity when starting the other activity..

Comment: @LiranRitkop When you have an app with multiple activities it becomes confusing to close them all, look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421004/how-to-close-application-when-multiple-activities-are-alive

Answer (score 0):

```
In Activty A Override  
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //start activity here
       Intent intent=new Intent(context,ActivtyB.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

In Activity B Override  
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //start activity here
       finish();
    }
```